# simple SQLPLUS issue.. my answer is wrong

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I need to Calculate the total number of days spent on resolving tickets for the month of
January 2012 for each tech personnel and List them in an ascending order.

I tried to rewrite the question make it more clear at first so here

Find all the tech ppls for the tickets in the month of jan 2012 and display the total number days spent on each.

Heres my attempt

```
select pplSoft, days_worked_on as pplWorkedOn 
from Tickets, Tech_personnel 
where date_submitted >= '01-JAN-2012' AND date_submitted <= '31-JAN-2012' 
group by pplSoft having pplWorkedOn =
   (select days_worked_on WHERE date_submitted >= '01-JAN-2012'
    AND date_submitted <= '31-JAN-2012');
```

Which is wrong.. help is appreciated!

```
TECH PERSONNEL (pplSoft, fname, lname, pittID, expertise, office phone) where fname is first name, and lname is last name.

USERS (pplSoft, fname, lname, pittID, office phone)

CATEGORIES (category id, category, description) where this table lists all possible categories of submitted tickets.

INVENTORY(machine name, IP, network port, MACADDR, location id)

LOCATIONS(location id, location, building, notes)

TICKETS (ticket number, owner pplSoft, date submitted, date closed, days worked on, category id, machine name, location, description)

ASSIGNMENT (ticket number, tech pplSoft, date assigned, status) where status held is an enumeration, could be: assigned, in progress, delegated, closed successful, or closed unsuccessful.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT owner_pplSoft, SUM(days_worked_on) AS sum_days_worked_on
FROM Tickets
WHERE date_submitted >= '01-JAN-2012' AND date_submitted <= '31-JAN-2012'
GROUP BY owner_pplSoft
ORDER BY SUM(days_worked_on)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the schema correctly...

```
SELECT PPLSOFT, SUM(DAYS_WORKED_ON)
FROM   TECH_PERSONNEL, TICKETS
WHERE  TECH_PERSONNEL.PPLSOFT = TICKETS.OWNER
AND    DATE_SUBMITTED >= TO_DATE('1/1/2012', 'DD/MM/YHYYY')
AND    DATE_SUBMITTED <= TO_DATE('31/1/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY PPLSOFT
ORDER BY PPLSOFT
```

or

```
ORDER BY SUM(DAYS_WORKED_ON) DESC
```

depending on which you want

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one is right :

```
select pplSoft, sum(TO_CHAR(todays_worked_on,'mm-dd-yyyy')) 
from Tickets tc, Tech_personnel tp
where tp.pplSoft=tc.pplSoft
and (date_submitted between TO_DATE('01-01-2012','mm-dd-yyyy') 
and TO_DATE('01-31-2012','mm-dd-yyyy'))
group by pplSoft,TO_CHAR(todays_worked_on,'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT owner_pplSoft as pplSoft, SUM(days_worked_on) AS pplWorkedOn 
FROM tickets
WHERE date_submitted >= to_date('01-JAN-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy') 
  AND date_submitted <= to_date('31-JAN-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
GROUP BY owner_pplSoft
ORDER BY SUM(days_worked_on)
```

Answer (score 0):

The PPLSOFT column on TICKETS is the owner, not the person working on the ticket.  To get the tech personnel you need to include ASSIGNMENTS in the mix.

```
select tech.pplSoft
       , sum(tic.days_worked_on) as pplWorkedOn 
from Tickets tic 
         join assignments ass on ( ass.ticket = tic.ticket )
         join Tech_personnel tech on ( ass.pplSoft = tech.pplSoft ) 
where ass.date_submitted >= to_date('01-JAN-2012') 
and ass.date_submitted <= to_date('31-JAN-2012')
group by tech.pplSoft
```

Now this probably still won't provide you with the answer you want.  This is because of flaws in your data model.

The DAYS_WORKED_ON column is held at the TICKET level, so if two people worked on the ticket the number of days would be double counted.  Also, the days worked throughout January for a ticket raised on 31-DEC-2011 would not be counted.  To get an accurate figure you need to track the days each person works on a ticket.

Although the ASSIGNMENTS.STATUS column seems to hold statuses relating to the TICKET.  Not sure whether this is another problem with your model or an indication that I have failed to understand the actual purpose of ASSIGNMENTS.

Comment: You are relying on implicit date conversion in your where clause. You should be using to_date functions.

Comment: @MikeMcAllister - actually I just cut'n'pasted the OP's code.  I normally only change what is relevant to the question in hand.  But I agree that not using a date function could create problems.

Comment: I considered making the comment on the OP's question, but thought it would be misleading, as the main problem was elsewhere.